# Create a date list with a "change of condition"

Tags: java, date, arraylist, jodatime

I've a date list (days of month) from a query and a date list (CoC) with a random number of dates.
I'm developing a java application to scan the days of month and write in output all the days of month and the relative date of other list when it changes.
I know, I'm uncleary but I've writed a simple code to make it clear to you.

This is my (wrong) code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.joda.time.MutableDateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int count_coc = 0;

        String[] month = {"2014-04-28", "2014-04-29", "2014-04-30", "2014-05-01",
                        "2014-05-02", "2014-05-03", "2014-05-04", "2014-05-05", "2014-05-06",
                        "2014-05-07", "2014-05-08", "2014-05-09", "2014-05-10", "2014-05-11",
                        "2014-05-12", "2014-05-13", "2014-05-14", "2014-05-15", "2014-05-16",
                        "2014-05-17", "2014-05-18", "2014-05-19", "2014-05-20", "2014-05-21",
                        "2014-05-22", "2014-05-23", "2014-05-24", "2014-05-25", "2014-05-26",
                        "2014-05-27", "2014-05-28", "2014-05-29", "2014-05-30", "2014-05-31", "2014-06-01"};

        String[] CoC = {"2014-04-30", "2014-05-15", "2014-05-24"};

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        MutableDateTime dateElab = new MutableDateTime(dtf.parseDateTime(month[0]));
        MutableDateTime dateLast = new MutableDateTime(dtf.parseDateTime(month[month.length-1]));
        ArrayList<MutableDateTime> dtJs = new ArrayList<MutableDateTime>();

        for (int i = 0; i<CoC.length;i++)
        {
         dtJs.add(new MutableDateTime(dtf.parseDateTime(CoC[i])));
        }

        do
        {
         if (dtJs.size() > 1)
         {
             if ((count_coc) < (dtJs.size()-1))
             {
                 if (dateElab.isBefore(dtJs.get(count_coc+1)) || dateElab.isEqual(dtJs.get(count_coc+1)))
                 {
                     System.out.println("Date month: " + dtf.print(dateElab) + "      Date CoC: " + dtf.print(dtJs.get(count_coc)));

                     if ((count_coc) > dtJs.size())
                     {
                             System.out.println("Date month: " + dtf.print(dateElab) + "      Date CoC: " + dtf.print(dtJs.get(count_coc)));
                     }
                     else
                     {
                             count_coc++;
                     }

                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Date month: " + dtf.print(dateElab) + "      Date CoC: " + dtf.print(dtJs.get(count_coc)));
             }

         }
         else
         {
                 System.out.println("Date month: " + dtf.print(dateElab) + "      Date CoC: " + dtf.print(dtJs.get(count_coc)));
         }

         dateElab.addDays(1);
        }
        while(dateElab.isBefore(dateLast) || dateElab.isEqual(dateLast));
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
Date month: 2014-04-28      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-04-29      Date CoC: 2014-05-15
Date month: 2014-04-30      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-01      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-02      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-03      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-04      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-05      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-06      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-07      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-08      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-09      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-10      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-11      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-12      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-13      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-14      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-15      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-16      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-17      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-18      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-19      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-20      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-21      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-22      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-23      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-24      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-25      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-26      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-27      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-28      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-29      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-30      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-31      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-06-01      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
```

This is my expected result:

```
Date month: 2014-04-28      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-04-29      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-04-30      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-01      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-02      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-03      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-04      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-05      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-06      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-07      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-08      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-09      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-10      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-11      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-12      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
Date month: 2014-05-13      Date CoC: 2014-04-30
(change date CoC)
Date month: 2014-05-14      Date CoC: 2014-05-14
Date month: 2014-05-16      Date CoC: 2014-05-14
Date month: 2014-05-17      Date CoC: 2014-05-14
Date month: 2014-05-18      Date CoC: 2014-05-14
Date month: 2014-05-19      Date CoC: 2014-05-14
Date month: 2014-05-20      Date CoC: 2014-05-14
Date month: 2014-05-21      Date CoC: 2014-05-14
Date month: 2014-05-22      Date CoC: 2014-05-14
Date month: 2014-05-23      Date CoC: 2014-05-14
(change date CoC)
Date month: 2014-05-24      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-25      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-26      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-27      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-28      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-29      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-30      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
Date month: 2014-05-31      Date CoC: 2014-05-24
```

Thanks so much!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your nested if will always be false, so else will be applied; thus count_coc++, that's why after two runs the last element of CoC is printed:
you have:

```
if ((count_coc) < (dtJs.size()-1)) {
    //other code
    if ((count_coc) > dtJs.size()) //this will always be false
```

Comment: Thanks man for reply! :) Yes, you're right...Anyway, there is something wrong in the logic of my code. I'm trying other solutions but it's very complex case...I'm losing all hopes...